# Unload SWF File in a Same Button that Load the External File to Minimize Loading Time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have two SWF files. First one is `home.swf` and the second one is `menu.swf`. Each SWF file has a button that load external SWF file.

This is the code inside `home.swf` file:

```
stop();
menu_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func_menu);
function func_menu(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("menu.swf"));
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    var movie:* = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget).content;
    stage.addChild(movie);
}
```

This is the code inside `menu.swf` file:

```
stop();
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, func_home);
function func_home(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("home.swf"));
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    var movie:* = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget).content;
    stage.addChild(movie);
}
```

If I click the buttons numerous times, the SWF files gets longer time to load. I notice that those code doesn't unload files. What code do I need to unload the previous SWF files?
I'm new in actionscript. Please go easy on me.

Comment: You load the same "swf" file multi times  which consume the memory of the device . I think you need to  load both "swf" files in the parent with one loader event listener , so you can use "loader.unloadAndStop();" before loading  the new swf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from the question that it's highly likely that you'll switch between the SWFs often (loading home and unloading menu, and vice versa).

I suggest you create a container SWF, which will load both SWFs, and save references to the loaders / their content on load complete.

Once both are loaded, simply call addChild() and removeChild() to swap them.

In case you want to trigger the swap from within the SWFs, you can dispatch an event when clicking on the buttons created in them, and listen to dispatched events in the container SWF.

That way you can swap them as many times as you'd like in an instant without having to reload them every time, plus you avoid constantly allocating and deallocating memory.